# Can I switch to the current terminal (file explorer) but not open a new one

Tags: pantheon-files, keyboard-shortcuts, pantheon-terminal

In the keyboard settings, we have shortcuts to open a terminal or file explorer, What I want to do is when I pressing  <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> switch to the current terminal, <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> switch to the file explorer.
It always opens a new one for me, which is I don't want to.

Comment: This behaviour is now implemented.